# psych.rb error when deploying with Capistrano 'mapping not allowed in this context'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app to a CentOS 6/nginx/passenger server, but cap deploy:cold is giving me an error. Here's the relevant part from deployment output:

```
  * 2013-03-31 17:49:59 executing `deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes'
  * executing "[ -e /home/appuser/apps/britaincares/shared/assets/manifest.yml ] && cat /home/appuser/apps/britaincares/shared/assets/manifest.yml || echo"
    servers: ["www.britaincares.co.uk"]
    [www.britaincares.co.uk] executing command
    command finished in 303ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/appuser/apps/britaincares/releases/20130331164733; true"
    servers: ["www.britaincares.co.uk"]
    [www.britaincares.co.uk] executing command
 ** [out :: www.britaincares.co.uk] /home/appuser/.bashrc: eval: line 26: syntax error: unexpected end of file
    command finished in 932ms
/Users/chriswickett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 28 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/assets.rb:63:in `block (3 levels) in load'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/callback.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `block in trigger'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `each'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `trigger'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:23:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/callback.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `block in trigger'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `each'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `trigger'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:27:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in `block in define_task'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:229:in `block (3 levels) in load'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:56:in `transaction'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:228:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in `block in define_task'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:517:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:46:in `block in execute_requested_actions'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `each'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `execute_requested_actions'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/cli/help.rb:19:in `execute_requested_actions_with_help'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:34:in `execute!'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/cap:19:in `load'
    from /Users/chriswickett/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374
```

Rails 3.2.1.

The manifest.yml file mentioned contains 'jquery.min.map' - is that what the 'mapping not allowed' part is referring to? If so, I can't work out how to stop jQuery trying to include this map file.

I've tried putting that contexts of the manifest.yml file through various online validators - it's coming up fine. No missing spaces or tabs as far as I can see.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this. Psych was being called because the file in Capistrano's `deploy/assets.rb` uses `YAML.load`.

The variable it was loading was a 'capture' of a command line cat command, and because my `.bashrc` had a syntax error in it, it was capturing the output of that error and passing it to `YAML.load`, too. Fixed `.bashrc` error and all is good!

Answer (score 19):

I had this issue and deleted my `.json` manifest files under `myapp/shared/assets`, as suggested [here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/451) (actually, they suggested renaming them, but that didn't work for me).

Comment: This worked for me. But I actually deleted the `manifest.yml` file. Rails 4 now uses .json including a bust-string in the file name.

Comment: This issue happens when you have two manifest files whether it is one .yml and one .json or even two .json ones. I discovered this after using capistrano-local-precompile which didn't remove the previous assets file and stopped me from deploying till I deleted the older manifest-<digest>.json file