# Psych error on Capistrano deployment

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, deployment, capistrano

I have a Capistrano deployment script which have work for some time, but now it throw such error on deployment:

```
/Users/lifecoder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/lifecoder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/lifecoder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
    from /Users/lifecoder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
...
```

It also throws several warnings during the deployment:

```
 ** [out :: test.domain] Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/lifecoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin' is not at first place,
 ** [out :: test.domain]
 ** [out :: test.domain] usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
 ** [out :: test.domain]
 ** [out :: test.domain] to fix run: 'rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448'.
```

I have found similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033816/why-am-i-getting-a-psych-error-when-trying-to-deploy-with-capistrano) and assume this warning is actually the cause of Psych crash. But I can't get rid of it, the PATH actually looks good for me, and rvm **is** in the first place when I connect via ssh and check it:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/lifecoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/home/lifecoder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/home/lifecoder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/home/lifecoder/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

I'm not so proficient in *nix so I probably miss something - but can't find what exactly.

I know it is probably fixable by YAML parser engine change, or by deleting YAML file somewhere so Psych wouldn't start, but I would prefer to fix this issue in the right way.

**UPD1**: I have add a hook with 'use rvm' into Capistrano script, and it return me 'RVM is not a function'. Seems it doesn't load bashrc/other init scripts.

**UPD2**: Yes, it does not load bash, but when I enable bash it become even worse. As a temporary solution I disabled capistrano/assets. Seems all I need is to wipe the copy-pasted capistrano script and rewrite it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Capistrano logs in - it uses non-interactive shell — it does not load .bash_profile
So, I've load a bash as a default shell in the **deployment.rb**:

```
default_run_options[:shell] = '/bin/bash'
```

and then move RVM load script from .bash_profile to .bashrc

```
#.bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc



#.bashrc
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```