# cap deploy:migrations: Error: control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please see the following error (control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)) and help me to resolve it.The error occur when I try to run the command "cap deploy:migrations" on ubuntu 12.10 ruby 1.9.3 Rails 3.2.0. There is local Apache server for deployment.

I have tried different solutions at stackoverflow but no one resolve the problem.

Thanks in advance

```
----------------------------------------
Error Detail:
----------------------------------------


imran@IJM:~/development/work/depot$ cap deploy:migrations
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2013-09-06 11:43:13 executing `deploy:migrations'
  * 2013-09-06 11:43:13 executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote imran@IJM:git/depot.git master"
    command finished in 359ms
.......
.......

  * executing "[ -e /home/imran/IJM/shared/assets/manifest* ] && cat /home/imran/IJM/shared/assets/manifest* || echo"
    servers: ["IJM"]
    [IJM] executing command
    command finished in 822ms
/home/imran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /home/imran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
    from /home/imran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
    from /home/imran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
    from /h
    from /home/imran/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/cap:19:in `load'
    from /home/imran/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/cap:19:in `<main>'
    from /home/imran/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/imran/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
deploy.rb
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---
# Excerpted from "Agile Web Development with Rails",
# published by The Pragmatic Bookshelf.
# Copyrights apply to this code. It may not be used to create training material, 
# courses, books, articles, and the like. Contact us if you are in doubt.
# We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose. 
# Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/rails4 for more book information.
#---

require 'bundler/capistrano'

# be sure to change these
set :user, 'imran'
set :domain, 'IJM'
set :application, 'depot'

# adjust if you are using RVM, remove if you are not
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3'
set :rvm_type, :user

# file paths
set :repository,  "#{user}@#{domain}:git/#{application}.git" 
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{domain}" 

# distribute your applications across servers (the instructions below put them
# all on the same server, defined above as 'domain', adjust as necessary)
role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db, domain, :primary => true

# you might need to set this if you aren't seeing password prompts
#default_run_options[:pty] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true
#default_run_options[:shell] = '/bin/bash'

# As Capistrano executes in a non-interactive mode and therefore doesn't cause
# any of your shell profile scripts to be run, the following might be needed
# if (for example) you have locally installed gems or applications.  Note:
# this needs to contain the full values for the variables set, not simply
# the deltas.
# default_environment['PATH']='<your paths>:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'
# default_environment['GEM_PATH']='<your paths>:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'
# miscellaneous options
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm, 'git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :scm_verbose, true
set :use_sudo, false
set :rails_env, :production
#IJM
#set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"

namespace :deploy do
  desc "cause Passenger to initiate a restart"
  task :restart do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"     
  end
  desc "reload the database with seed data"
  task :seed do
    run "cd #{current_path}; rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
end
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.bashrc
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
#PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
#[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"


# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.bash_profile
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && \
. "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
#source ~/.bashrc

export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Maybe check if that applies to you https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/929 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033816/why-am-i-getting-a-psych-error-when-trying-to-deploy-with-capistrano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem last week, I fixed with this

"it's your hook /home/rails/.rvm/hooks/after_use_textmate - disable it (chmod -x) and rvm will not generate wrappers for it anymore."

Based in this issue https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1964#issuecomment-19410325

Comment: Dear Rderoldan problem has been resolved with your solution. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Dear Rederoldan vote up required 15 reputation but I don't have.