# "control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)" during gem install or bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

When attempting to install Rails gems with `bundle install` I kept getting an error "control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1" when bundler tried to `gem install` some gems, like Nokogiri.

```
$ gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.6.2
Fetching: mini_portile-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile-0.6.2
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: (<unknown>): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError) in /var/www/.rvm/gems/ext-rbx-2.5.2@rails2/cache/nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem
```

Here are some similar questions:

[cap deploy:migrations: Error: control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652299/cap-deploymigrations-error-control-characters-are-not-allowed-at-line-1-colum)

(I think my question is not a duplicate because in this case the error occurred when using bundle install, while in the case above it happened when deploying with capistrano, but I admit this question is very similar.)

[Why am I getting a Psych error when trying to deploy with capistrano?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033816/why-am-i-getting-a-psych-error-when-trying-to-deploy-with-capistrano)

[psych.rb error when deploying with Capistrano 'mapping not allowed in this context'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732014/psych-rb-error-when-deploying-with-capistrano-mapping-not-allowed-in-this-conte)

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was to execute this before `bundle install`:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

From sergiocampama: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/929#issuecomment-17964326

Add that to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` to prevent this problem in the future.

Disclaimer: I haven't investigated what these variables do and I don't know if they are correct for everyone, like non-English environments.