# How to disable rvm output when use capstrano deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano

I'm setting up a new server, with RVM, CAPSTRANO.

but when i deploy the server, i got a error:

```
  * 2013-06-13 16:39:50 executing `deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes'
  * executing "[ -e /home/rails/server/blog/shared/assets/manifest.yml ] && cat /home/rails/server/blog/shared/assets/manifest.yml || echo"
    servers: ["121.196.130.171"]
    [121.196.130.171] executing command
    command finished in 1600ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/rails/server/blog/releases/20130613083928; true"
    servers: ["121.196.130.171"]
    [121.196.130.171] executing command
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] Saving wrappers to '/data/home/rails/.rvm//bin'
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] 
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] Saving wrappers to '/data/home/rails/.rvm//bin'
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] 
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] Saving wrappers to '/data/home/rails/.rvm//bin'
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] .
 ** [out :: 121.196.130.171] 
    command finished in 1610ms
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

i found answer from this :
[psych.rb error when deploying with Capistrano 'mapping not allowed in this context'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732014/psych-rb-error-when-deploying-with-capistrano-mapping-not-allowed-in-this-conte)

but How can i disable the output "Saving wrappers to ......." when i use cap ?
and also for bash shell "rvm use ***" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found that rvm stopped printing "Saving wrappers to ......." when I followed mpapis' advice on https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1964#issuecomment-19437861, namely, to remove execute permissions from the `after_user_textmate` hook on your rvm installation.

For my system, I ran (sustitute your own rvm installation directory):

```
chmod a-x /usr/local/rvm/hooks/after_use_textmate
```