# Deploy Error - psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 6 (Psych::SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Due to network timeout, it seems the deployment couldn't complete and I had to CTRL + C to rollback. Now when I am trying to deploy again, it is giving below error.

I am unsure why this is happening since nothing has been changed/edited either locally or on server. It looks like some setting of Capistrano got corrupted/ Can you suggest what options I have to fix this ?

The deploy.rb file looks fine since I have used it till now for all the deployment. There is no problem with whenever too.

```
*** [whenever:update_crontab] rolling back
  * executing "ls -x /home/jason/apps/leads/releases"
    servers: ["64.103.76.29"]
    [64.103.76.29] executing command
    command finished in 669ms
  * executing "cd /home/jason/app/releases/20160418060908 && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab leads --set environment=production --roles db"
    servers: ["64.103.76.29"]
    [64.103.76.29] executing command
 ** [out :: 64.103.76.29] [write] crontab file updated
    command finished in 1135ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/jason/app/releases/20160418120015; true"
    servers: ["64.103.76.29"]
    [64.103.76.29] executing command
    command finished in 712ms
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 6 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/assets.rb:26:in `parse_manifest'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
```

EDIT - The 2nd comment link [psych.rb error when deploying with Capistrano 'mapping not allowed in this context'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732014/psych-rb-error-when-deploying-with-capistrano-mapping-not-allowed-in-this-conte) solved the issue. There were 2 manifest json files, I deleted both and now it got deployed.

Comment: Can you please run [this script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9848226/5006469)? You have a bad YAML file somewhere.

Comment: @standelaune Thanks, I ran the script, it showed "Checkigng" for about 15 files but gave no error.

Comment: Mmh okay. What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15732014/5006469)?

Comment: @standelaune - My apologies, I ran the 1st script on server and got above output (in post). It seems many gems have incorrect yml syntax, I am not sure they got corrupted due to forceful restart of the app or because this is permission issue.

Comment: Be carreful, the invalid yml you point out are test data, under `invalid` folder. This is not relevant.

Comment: @standelaune - 2nd link solved the problem. Thanks a lot. :)